# VBA - Copying worksheet from one workbook to another (values, not formulas)

Tags: vba, excel

Currently, I am copying the values and formats of a worksheet to a worksheet in another workbook as such:

```
workbooks("book1.xlsm").sheets(1).range(someRange).copy
with workbooks("book2.xlsm").sheets(1).range("A1")
    .pasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .pasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
end with
```

I would like to use something like:

```
workbooks("book1.xlsm").sheet(1).copy after:=workbooks("book2.xlsm").sheet(1)
```

The problem is that some of the cells in sheet(1) of book1.xlsm have formulas. Using the second method pulls the formulas, and the resulting values are linked to the data in book2.xlsm

How can I use the second method, but have the values, not formulas, copied?

If not possible, what are some alternatives, aside from the first method, which I am currently using?

Comment: What is wrong with the first method? It seems perfectly fine and has always worked for me.

Comment: Agree with @ChipsLetten; do you simply want something on 1 line?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the first method. I was just wondering there was a way to make the second method suit my needs, or there were any alternatives that I was overlooking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break the links after the copy operation:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copySheetValues()

    With Workbooks("Book2")

        Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets(1).Copy After:=.Worksheets(1)

        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01") 'built-in replacement for "Sleep"

        .BreakLink Name:=Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").FullName, Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks

    End With

End Sub
```

---

Note: both files need to be open in the same instance of the Excel application

Comment: I'm getting an error: " Run-time error '1004: Method 'BreakLink' of object '_Workbook' failed" Thank you for your response, though

Comment: I fixed it by adding a delay of 1 second before breaking the links

Comment: Thanks for the update. I got your code to work by changing `Name:=.Name` to `Name:=Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").FullName`

Comment: thanks for the feedback - I updated the answer accordingly