# How to save workbook with computed values, not formulas?

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, xlwings

I'm using Python 3.6, xlwings 0.11.4 and Excel 2016 on Windows 10. I'd like to load and save a copy of a workbook with data computed by formulas, not the formulas. E.g. if `test.xlsx` contained `=1+1` in cell A1, `copy.xlsx` should contain `2` in cell A1.

```
import xlwings
wb = xlwings.Book('test.xlsx')
wb.save('copy.xlsx')  # Something like break_links or data_only=True?
```

I can do this with `openpyxl` using [`data_only`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html), but unfortunately `openpyxl` does not support image loading which is a requirement in my current project.

I know it's possible to manually [read and set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925185/how-to-get-formula-result-in-excel-using-xlwings) every computed value, but I'm looking for a built-in / quick way to '[break formula links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31863861/1072869)' automatically on save. Thanks

Comment: You can use `Pandas` with `openpyxl` to convert `xlxs` to `csv` and back to `xlsx`, and it only take seconds.  Let me know and I can post some sample code for you to try.

Comment: I don't know of anything built in, but the first method contained in the VBA *question* you linked to looks fine to me. Can't you just use the xlwings equivalent of that? (For that matter, I agree with the people who don't understand why the asker of that question isn't happy with that method. That they are already using. Successfully.)

Comment: @ian0411 `csv` wouldn't preserve my images, which I need. @John I'm pretty new to xlwings, and I cant find a `paste` with a quick search in the API docs. Do you know how to implement this? Btw, I want to avoid using `win32com` to call `pasteSpecial` for now, to avoid the loss of cross-platform code gained with xlwings